# Which analysis text has a content viewing uniform convergence as a convergence in a function space?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm taking elementary analysis this year and I have a test about uniform convergence tomorrow.

While I was studying this, I realized that the concept of uniform convergence can be generalized into a function space, and consider "uniform convergence" as just "convergence.

That is;

> Let $(V,||\cdot||)$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{K}$.
>
> Let $I$ be a set.
>
> Let $d$ be the metric induced by $||\cdot||$.
>
> Let $\overline{d}$ be the standard bounded metric of $d$.
>
> Now define $\overline{\rho}(f,g)=\sup_{x\in I} \overline{d}(f(x),g(x))$.
>
> Well, this is the definition of "uniform metric" in Munkres-Topology.
>
> Then, I have showed that the piecewise operations $+,\cdot$ on $V^I$ are continuous, so that $V^I$ is a topological vector space.

With above structure on $V^I$, It can be shown that $V^I$ is a topological vector space and $\overline{\rho}$ is a complete metric on $V^I$.

> I was trying to find a norm on $V^I$ which makes $V^I$ a Banach space such that convergence of $\{f_n\}$ in $V^I$ is indeed a uniform convergence of $\{f_n\}$ in $V$, but I couldn't find a such norm.

I like Munkre's definition of $\overline{\rho}$ since it enables one to define over an arbitrary $I$, not restricting on $B(I,V)$.

Which text has this content with this viewpoint?

I'm asking this since there's no functional analysis text by Munkres..

Comment: Is the "standard bounded metric of $d$" given by $\overline{d}(x,y) = \min \{ d(x,y), 1\}$, or by $\overline{d}(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$, or by what? [It may be standard for Munkres' book, but there's no universal such "standard bounded metric".] Anyway, $V^I$ is in general not a topological vector space with either of the two constructions above. Take $I = V = \mathbb{K}$, and $f = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{K}}$. In a topological vector space, $2^{-n}\cdot f$ would converge to $0$, but with both constructions above you have $\overline{\rho}(2^{-n}f,0) = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then what is a correct approach to view uniform convergence as a convergence in a function space? so that even uniform convergence of series is a convergence of a sequence in a function space?

Comment: On spaces of bounded functions with values in some topological vector space, uniform convergence gives you a nice vector space topology. Without the boundedness assumption, uniform convergence gives you a nice uniform structure on space of functions with values in a uniform space. If that uniform space is a topological group (maybe we need to require it abelian, I'd have to think about that), we get a nice topological group structure.

Comment: Then, on locally compact (Hausdorff) spaces, you get a TVS topology by looking at _locally uniform convergence_ for spaces of continuous functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer Are those terms "uniform structure" and "Entourage" from functional analysis? Which subject is that studying those?

Comment: Topology. In functional analysis, it is quite helpful to know some topology.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you recommend me a topology text including chapters introducing those rigorously? I have studied two point-set topology texts but there was none about it..

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I'm not well-versed in the literature. My topology book is long out of print [and in German, which might or might not be a problem], and I don't know who handles uniform spaces nowadays. There's always Bourbaki of course, but that's more of a reference than something to learn from.

Comment: @DanielFischer What do you mean? Why is uniform space obsolete? and yeah.. I hope someone translates Bourbaki to English.. I love Bourbaki's approach but can't read french..

Comment: They aren't. It's just that introductory topology texts often don't treat uniform spaces, since they're considered too advanced for an introduction. I don't know which introductory texts treat them. Nor do I know which other texts treat them. I know there are books which do, since uniform spaces are important (although mostly in the flavours of metric spaces or topological groups), but not which. I'm not acquainted with much of the literature, books are expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Charles Chapman Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis* and Kenneth Hoffman's *Analysis on Euclidean Space* have extensive introductory treatments of analysis on function spaces. Both are introductory and require only basic analysis on metric spaces. These,to me,are 2 of the very best intermediate analysis textbooks available.